# TypeError: callback is not a function in AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build my first angular app, I keep getting a error that callback is not a function when trying to save my factory into a service so I can use it for the life of the app.

Here is what I have so far

```
angular.module('games', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    //take out #
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('games', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/static/app/list.html",
            controller: 'gamesCtrl'
        })
    $stateProvider
        .state('game', {
            url: "/games/:title",
            templateUrl: "/static/app/page.html",
            controller: 'pageCtrl'
        })
})

.controller('gamesCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'gamesService',
    function($scope, $state, gamesService) {
         $scope.$state = $state;
         $scope.games = null;

         function init() {
           gamesService.getGames().success(function(games) {
             $scope.games = games.data;
             console.log($scope.games.data)
           });

         }
         init();
    }

])

.service('gamesService', ['gamesFactory',
    function(gamesFactory) {
        //grab the list of games on load
        var gamesList = [];
        gamesFactory.getGames().success(function(games) {
            gamesList = games
        });

        this.getGames = function(callback){
            callback(gamesList);
        }
    }
])

.factory('gamesFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getGames = function() {
        return $http.get('/games.json');
    };
    return factory;
});
```

My error is occuring here

```
.service('gamesService', ['gamesFactory',
    function(gamesFactory) {
        //grab the list of games on load
        var gamesList = [];
        gamesFactory.getGames().success(function(games) {
            gamesList = games
        });

        this.getGames = function(callback){
            callback(gamesList);
        }
    }
])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should consider using `.then()` instead of `.success()` with `$http` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should do this. getGames is expecting a callback, and since you dint pass it, it is undefined. GameFactory and GameService both have getGames named function which is confusing and that might have caused you to do a minor mistake. The function getGames in gameService expects a callback and there is no check in place to test whether the callback was passed.

**Step 1:**

Change the this.getGames function in gameService.

```
    this.getGames = function(callback){
     if(callback and typeof callback==='function'){
       callback(gamesList);
     } 
    }
```

**Step 2**

I am guessing this based on your "success" attempt in the question.

```
function init() {
       gamesService.getGames(function(games) {
         $scope.games = games.data;
         console.log($scope.games.data)
       });

     }
```

You must always validate your arguments and perform actions on them to ensure error handling and also to make sure the script does not stop because of unexpected errors.